# Actionscript 3.0 platformer game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an flash game with the following code (http://pastie.org/9248528)

When I run it, the player just falls and doesn't stop when he hits a platform.
I tried debugging it and I had an error with moveCharacter's timer, but I don't know if that is the main problem.

I put the player inside the wall and debugged it using breakpoints and it didn't detect that the player was inside the wall, skipping moving it to outside of the wall.

Anyone has any ideas on what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Yeah I don't like using Flash either, it is just required for the assignment I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
// Check if character falls off any platform
    for (var i:int = 0; i < platform.length; i++) {
        if (player.x < platform[i].x || player.x > platform[i].x + platform[i].width) {
            onPlatform = false;
        }
    }
```

Since the player cannot simultaneously be on every platform at once, his x position is pretty much guaranteed to be out of bounds of at least 1 platform, which will set onPlatform to false.  Instead you would need to keep a reference to which platform the player is on, like so:

```
var lastPlatform:Sprite; //holds reference to last platform player was on
// Function to move character
function moveCharacter(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    ....
    // Check if character falls off the platform he was last on
    if (lastPlatform != null && (player.x < lastPlatform.x || player.x > lastPlatform.x + lastPlatform.width)) {
        onPlatform = false;
    }
}
function detectCollisions():void {
    // Check for collisions with platforms 
    for (var p:int = 0; p < platform.length; p++) {
        // Adjust character to platform level if with landing depth of the platform
        if (!onPlatform && player.hitTestObject(platform[p]) && lastPosY < platform[p].y) {
            lastPlatform = platform[p]; //save reference
            player.y = platform[p].y;
            jumping = false;
            onPlatform = true;
            dy = 0;
        // Prevent character from dropping sideways into platforms
        } else if (!onPlatform && player.hitTestObject(platform[p])) {
            player.x = lastPosX;
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

This should work better, though it is still not the most object-oriented way to do this. Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 i think Gigggas put more effort into this than op

Comment: thanks, now he doesn't fall through the platforms, but he can't jump.

Comment: actually he only stays at 922 because of the if player.x > 922 code.
he falls through the other platforms aswell

Comment: I edited the detectCollision() code slightly so that it doesn't try checking if the player is colliding with a platform if it already knows he is on the platform.  That might fix the no jumping problem at least.